# Do I require to put my middle name in the for when I apply for a driver's license or a bank account in Australia?

Tags: australia, paperwork, legal, names

Do I require to put my middle name when I apply for a driver's license or a bank account in Australia? I prefer to only use my short first and last name in daily life but do I still need to announce my middle name for work or other things?

More accurately my question is about identity verification. I, for example, apply up for a service by providing only my first and last name and they look at my driver's licence that possibly has my middle name, will it be considered a mismatch?

related: https://www.homeaffairs.gov.au/criminal-justice/files/recording-name-establish-identity.pdf